# My extended observable is getting "deleted" after call to ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping

I have an observable extended with the following extender:

```
ko.extenders.e2mElementName = function (target, options) {

    var result = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: target,
        write: function (newValue) {
            var current = target.peek();
            if (newValue != current) {

                newValue = newValue.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z_]/g, "").replace(" ", "_");

                //check if name already exists
                if (!document._editor.elementNames)
                    document._editor.elementNames = [];

                if ($.inArray(newValue, document._editor.elementNames)) {
                    alert("The name '" + newValue + "' was already assigned to an element on this page");
                    target.notifySubscribers(current)
                } else {
                    document._editor.elementNames.remove(current);
                    document._editor.elementNames.push(newValue);
                    target(newValue);
                }

            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    //result(target());

    return result;
};
```

When i extend the observable at construction everything works fine, in my object construction i have:

```
this.Name = ko.observable("").extend({ e2mElementName: true });
```

but after i make a call to mapping.fromJs my observable gets changed to a string ex: "My Name" ...

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(rawData, mapping, this);
```

if I remove the extender everything works fine and i have the observable wrapping the string....

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the extender after calling the ko.mapping.fromJS

```
var applyMapping = function(rawData) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(rawData, {}, this);
  this.name = this.name.extend({e2ElementName: true});
}
```

or you can use the mapping plugin options for this

```
var mappingOptions = {
  // customize the creation of the name property
  name: {
    create: function(data) {
        return ko.observable(data.name).extend( {e2ElementName: true} );
    }
  }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, this));
```